# Print out likes minus $_SESSION['id']

Tags: php

I am printing out my user likes in a stream..And currently when printing out the likes it prints with the $_SESSION['id'] included for the given post. How would I edit this code to just echo out the likes of user2?

```
$likesqltwo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM streamdata_feedback WHERE feedback_streamid ='$streamid' AND feedback_rating = 1");
$num3 = mysql_num_rows($likesqltwo);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($likesqltwo)){

$likes=rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($row['feedback_userid']); 
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$user2_id=$row['feedback_userid'];

if($user2_id==$_SESSION['id']){
    echo"";
}else{
    echo "And <a title = 'See who likes " .
        $poster_name['fullusersname'] .
        "s status' href='include/likes.php?streamitem_id=" .
        $streamitem_data['streamitem_id']."' />" . 
        $num3 . " ";

}

}
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_*` functions as they are [now deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [Be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @Peehaa, surely you won't begrudge me when we have the same point.

Comment: Stating that it is already deprecated only confuses people. As stated on internals: Don't panic

Comment: When I get around to editing my whole site..I will updae my code..Until then for purposes of just learning php it will do. The deprecated sign is not going to show up for the next release of PHP so I have enough time to update my code.

Now back to my question..Can anyone help please?

Comment: I like how we're judging his coding knowledge rather than answering his question.  @dave - Can you post what is being output by this script?

Comment: Don't worry Jordan. I get it all the time lately. But I'll be getting around to it in a weeks time when I get two weeks off work. :)

Comment: Its outputting everything correct.. I liked a comment and user2 a friend liked the same comment. The output is 2 likes. Tho I want to hide my like and only show my friends like of that post. Or do you mean my SQL output?